# Graphical breadcrumb for Emacs

Tags: emacs, breadcrumbs, graphical-interaction

Anyone know of any graphical breadcrumbs for Emacs? I would like to have the path to the file I am currently editing displayed on top somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
(defun my-breadcrumb (path)
  "Return path in a breadcrumb format."
  (mapconcat 'identity
             (split-string path (char-to-string directory-sep-char) t)
             " > "))

(setq frame-title-format
      '(buffer-file-name
        (:eval (my-breadcrumb buffer-file-name))
        (dired-directory
         (:eval (my-breadcrumb dired-directory))
         ("%b"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a breadcrumb but I have the buffer name and the path file in the window bar:

`(setq frame-title-format '(buffer-file-name "Emacs :  %b  ( %f )" "Emacs: %b"))`